# Devise Rollback on Signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Afternoon All,

I'm trying to use carrierwave to upload a picture on sign-up. Could anyone tell me why the params is rolling back or point me in the right direction. I am using devise's standard registrations controller and haven't created my own.

```
    Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-20 15:16:15 +0100
    Processing by Devise::RegistrationsController#create as HTML
      Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"bB/oSY5s5ohDqivn63sbbehPxQxzkVlt5WVB7BDYNsI=", 
"user"=>{"first_name"=>"Shaun", "last_name"=>"Shaun", 
"profile_name"=>"Shaunj9k", "email"=>"shaun@shaun.com", 
"password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]",
 "avatar"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f3d94a114d0 
@tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20131120-18938-onc1k9>, @original_filename="12673_607433832654038_1101803441_n.jpg",
 @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"12673_607433832654038_1101803441_n.jpg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">, 
"avatar_cache"=>""}, 
"commit"=>"Sign up"}
       (0.7ms)  BEGIN
      User Exists (71.8ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'shaun@shaun.com' LIMIT 1
       (0.3ms)  ROLLBACK
```

Ok, I've been trying to figure this out all night. I have now created a custom controller and stuck pry inside it. This is the process shown below:

```
 def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)
binding.pry
    if resource.save
      yield resource if block_given?
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_flashing_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_flashing_format?
        expire_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end

  end
```

So when I get to this breakpoint and inspect params, this is what is shown, right before it jumps to else:

```
[2] pry(#<RegistrationsController>)> sign_up_params
=> {"first_name"=>"Marlene",
 "last_name"=>"Annoying",
 "profile_name"=>"AnnoyingMarlene",
 "email"=>"mannoying@smelly.com",
 "password"=>"admin1234",
 "password_confirmation"=>"admin1234",
 "avatar"=>
  #<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0xb2f69d18
   @content_type="image/jpeg",
   @headers=
    "Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"user[avatar]\"; filename=\"picture.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n",
   @original_filename="picture.jpeg",
   @tempfile=#<File:/tmp/RackMultipart20131121-14703-1fubdpu>>,
 "avatar_cache"=>"1385025876-14703-8014/Link_to_sublime_text"}
```

Here is the store dir in AvatarUploader.rb

```
 def store_dir
    "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
  end
```

Comment: What can you find inside the `@user.errors.full_messages` array in the `create` action?

Comment: I'm using devise's registrations controller so how would I show that.

Comment: Uhm, a quick way: try using `User.create!({ ... })` with the same params in `pry`. Then look for errors

Comment: No errors parsed and it committed to database...

Comment: @marzapower Any other ideas why this wouldn't be passing?

Comment: Try using a custom controller with devise: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#configuring-controllers. Then debug those error messages (if any)

Comment: @marzapower I've updated the question but still doesn't make any sense. Is it saving to the correct directory?

Comment: Probably Devise is trying to handle the avatar images for resizing using the temp directory but it's not capable of writing on `/tmp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. Carrierwave doesn't like it when install imagemagick via source. If you are using ubuntu make sure you install using

```
sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

Then mini-magick seems to talk correctly to imagemagick and voila I now have profile picture.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is self-explanatory: `User Exists`. Probably you already have a user in the database with `"email" = 'shaun@shaun.com'`, and this email has to be unique.

Comment: Did you try to `rake db:reset` the database?

Comment: Updated question, blank database still saying user exist?

Answer (score 1):

if you are using .save, just put @object.errors then check in the console what's the error message

if you are using .save! change it to .save then see above

Answer (score 0):

Try User.delete_all if there isn't any other users and try again.
Also which database are you using ?